# Calculating number of validators on dune

Tags: ether, eth-2.0, staking, validators, dune

to find total validators on eth , i am using below logics >>
SELECT sum(amount_staked) FROM staking_ethereum.deposits  as a,
SELECT sum(amount)/1e9 FROM ethereum.withdrawals as b ,
and my output is (a-b)/32 ,
am i making a mistake